# Hang on jabber-connect in emacs

Tags: emacs, jabber

I use [jabber.el](http://emacs-jabber.sourceforge.net/) to connect to my work chat server from within `emacs`. This was working until recently, but now when I run `jabber-connect` it hangs after prompting for my JID. Emacs locks up until I cancel it with `C-g`, at which point I see:

```
Buffer " *-jabber-process-*" has a running process; kill it? (y or n)
```

...in the minibuffer, and I have to answer `y` to get out.

In the `*Messages*` buffer, I can see these other messages:

```
Opening TLS connection to `lxchat'...
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 5223 lxchat'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 5223 lxchat --protocols ssl3'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `openssl s_client -connect lxchat:5223 -no_ssl2 -ign_eof'...
```

If I try running the `openssl_client` command from the command line, it seems to connect successfully. Although I guess that just shows it can establish the SSL connection?

```
~> openssl s_client -connect lxchat:5223 -no_ssl2 -ign_eof
CONNECTED(00000003)
^C
```

What else can I do to work out what the problem is?

Comment: When I try that openssl command line to `www.google.com:443`, it spits out lots of certificate information after the `CONNECTED` line.  Perhaps your server accepts the connection but never completes the SSL handshake?..

Comment: Hmm, you're right - also, if I run that command from a different host, I get a whole lot of certificate output. Ok, that gives me something useful to go on. Thanks!

Comment: I use jabber.el to connect to Hipchat I think it sometimes hangs Emacs when someone sends me an emoji. And very often for no apparent reason Emacs just dies. The main culprit is jabber.el. I tried working without connecting for a few days. And I think Emacs a lot more stable without it. Although I really want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I avoid making Emacs deal with the network directly. Though things have improved significantly, single-threaded Emacs will hang at inconvenient moments. When you have elisp implementations of things like jabber, it helps to keep a single Emacs config across platforms, but if you do not have this need, it is easier and often less long-term hassle to use platform-specific tools. For instance, I use [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net) to send email and a combination of [bitlbee](https://www.bitlbee.org/) and ERC to connect to various IM networks.